# Can anyone tell if it is m.2 PCIe gen3x4 port?

Tags: ssd, pci-express, hardware-rec, m.2

Can anyone tell is it **PCIe gen3x4** m.2 ssd port? Will it support **m.2 nvme ssd**?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you check the manual for the motherboard?  That port most definitely is NOT a NVMe M.2 (nor is it PCIe 3 x4)

Comment: Indeed system part number or motherboard type would help a lot here.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have asus X507UF laptop, above pictures are of that laptop's motherboard, I could not found information regarding the motherboard of this laptop. I watched some videos on youtube, they put nvme ssd on same modal, I'm confused because some manufacturer delivers different products in different countries with same modal

Comment: Yes; You are right; different regions have different models. Your in the best position to know what region the device came from